pmset: Error 0xe00002db cancelling all scheduled events
I get the following behavior on my mac.
> sudo pmset schedule cancelall
pmset: Error 0xe00002db cancelling all scheduled events

> sudo pmset schedule cancel wake '04/13/2024 09:27:02'
pmset: Error in scheduling operation

This used to work just fine, suggesting that I have set the right power management settings. I don't believe I have changed any settings here, especially given that I can schedule wake events just fine still.
On my current environment:

Macbook Air M1 2020, 8GB, Sonoma 14.2.1

I currently have 1000 wakes scheduled, which is the max allowed on Mac OS. I have done this repeatedly. Schedule 1000, cancel 1000, schedule 1000, cancel 1000, and so on (debugging a Python script). I suppose macOS's security systems may have somehow detected "malicious" behavior, but I'm not sure.

I believe a workaround is to disable SIP, cancel all, re-enable SIP, but I'd prefer not to do this. If this is the only way I can cancel these wakes, then please let me know. I currently have SIP Enabled.


> csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: enabled.


Another workaround, if the answer is "yes, it will be disabled, but only for 24 hours" is to simply wait 24 hours... that's fine by me.


Does this answer your question? pmset: Error 0xe00002bc and Error when using "pmset sleepnow" both return the same error and show similar behaviour.

Those posts did not answer the question. However, I did figure it out. I believe it was simply a security protocol from MacOS. I was scheduling and unscheduling thousands of events while debugging, and I must have hit a rate limit. After a few hours, the command executed as expected.

Good to hear the problem is no longer critical. Please can you add your solution as an answer to this question, then the question can be marked as complete.
